# The Halachic issues for the preparation of Green Loose Leaf tea

Tags: halacha, stringency-chumrah

What are the halachic issues regarding a tea which is brewed with a bug on one or more of the leaves?

Either for;

a) Loose leaf tea 
b) In a tea bag

Answer (score 1):

you can not drink it with the bug (having the bug come into your mouth),

### so you need to filter the liquid until you know that the bug is not there (for example by taking out the teabag) and then you can drink it.

(it seems you may drink it while the tea bag is inside (since the bug will not get into your mouth) but you will be acting like a "bad man" (see below))
S"A Y"D [104.3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De%27ah.104.3)

but is you are disgusted by it, it might be forbidden to drink it
S"A Y"D [116.6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De%27ah.116.6)

---

not halachik

Talmud Gittin [90a](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.90a.15)

> It is taught in a baraita (Tosefta, Sota 5:9) that Rabbi Meir would say: Just as there are different attitudes with regard to food, so too, there are different attitudes with regard to women:
> With regard to food, you have a person who, **when a fly falls into his cup, he throws out the wine with the fly and does not drink it.** And this is comparable to the demeanor of Pappos ben Yehuda with regard to his wife, as he would lock the door before his wife and leave so that she would not see any other man. *(not proper behavior (rash))*
>
> **And you have a person who, when a fly falls into his cup, he throws out the fly and drinks the wine. And this is comparable to the demeanor of any common man** , whose wife speaks with her siblings and relatives, and he lets her do so.
>
> **And you have a man who, when a fly falls into his serving bowl, he sucks the fly and eats the food.** This is the demeanor of a **bad man**, who sees his wife going out into the street with her head uncovered, and spinning in the marketplace immodestly,